# How can I perform a recursive template within a recursive template in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, xslt-1.0

I am trying to perform a recursive template within a recursive template but I am unable to

```
<xsl:template match="feed">
    <xsl:call-template name="recursiveLoop">
        <!-- for loop pass in params -->
    </xsl:call-template>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="recursiveLoop">     
    <xsl:if test="$count &lt; 12">
        <!-- loop through 12 times -->
        <!-- sort months and get data -->

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($realCurrentMonth + $count = $outboundMonthFromDoc) or ($tempMonthToDisplay = $outboundMonthFromDoc)">
                <p><xsl:text>price is available</xsl:text></p>                              
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>             
                <xsl:call-template name="loopToFindCorrectMonth">
                    <xsl:with-param name="count2" select="0"/>                  
                </xsl:call-template>                    
                <xsl:template name="loopToFindCorrectMonth">
                    <xsl:param name="count2"/>
                    <xsl:if test="$count2 &lt; 12">
                        <xsl:text>hello</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:call-template name="loopToFindCorrectMonth">
                            <xsl:with-param name="count2" select="$count2 + 1"/>            
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:if>           
                </xsl:template>                 
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>   

        <xsl:call-template name="recursiveLoop">
            <!-- pass params in again -->
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

My first loop is 'recursiveLoop' and my second loop is 'loopToFindCorrectMonth'. However, the 2nd loop never works. When I remove the loop and replace it with a simple output statement like below then it works. So there is something wrong with the 2nd loop and I don't know what it is.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="($realCurrentMonth + $count = $outboundMonthFromDoc) or ($tempMonthToDisplay = $outboundMonthFromDoc)">
        <p><xsl:text>price is available</xsl:text></p>                              
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>             
        <p><xsl:text>Loop has been removed</xsl:text></p>   
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: `xsl:template` needs to be a top-level element, i.e. a direct child of `xsl:stylesheet`. You can't nest an `xsl:template` inside another template as you have tried. So with your code snippet you should get an error.

Comment: That's the correct answer thanks